# Convert SQL query to yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

Until now I have been using a SQL query in `yii2` which was working fine locally but as soon as I deploy it to the server it shows

[image: image.jpt]

I have tried changing it to yii query since its a proper implementation below

```
$query = $connection->createCommand("SELECT a.name_of_flight, a.time_of_flight, (a.no_of_passenger - b.cnt) as avail, a.no_of_passenger FROM flight_schedule a LEFT JOIN (SELECT flight_time, COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM book_eticket WHERE flight_date='$date' AND company_name = '$comp_name' GROUP BY flight_time) b ON a.id = b.flight_time")->queryAll();
```

to

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query());

$query
    ->select('a.name_of_flight, a.time_of_flight, (a.no_of_passenger - b.cnt) as avail, a.no_of_passenger')
    ->from('flight_schedule a')
    ->leftJoin('flight_time', ('COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM book_eticket'))
    ->where(array('and', 'flight_date=2016-6-29', 'company_name = Team5'))
    ->groupBy(['flight_time b','ON a.id = b.flight_time']);

$command = $query->createCommand();
$query = $command->queryAll();
```

but I get an error:

[image]

Can anybody help me find out the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: about first: you probably doing something wrong. Can you provide you db config?

Comment: about second pls provide full error (raw text ) with sql

Comment: $query = $connection->createCommand("SELECT a.name_of_flight, a.time_of_flight, (a.no_of_passenger - b.cnt) as avail, a.no_of_passenger FROM flight_schedule a LEFT JOIN (SELECT flight_time, COUNT(id) AS cnt FROM book_eticket WHERE flight_date='$date' AND company_name = '$comp_name' GROUP BY flight_time) b ON a.id = b.flight_time")->queryAll();

Answer (score 1):

First screen says about access issues. Second - that operands like *date* and *team* is not string. That is wrong. Can you quote them?

Comment: yes first screen is the server not giving sql access since password is needed and the date and time is static since for testing only so..i need to convert in yii